# Checking whether a user is logged into Flattr?

Tags: flattr

Is there a way to test whether a user is logged into Flattr?

The idea is to set up a "I'm-ready-to-donate-wall" that only Flattr users are allowed to pass. However, unlike a paywall, the user is *not* forced to click a flattr button; I just want to make sure that he's ready to flattr anything if he/she likes what he/she sees. I am not interested in his/her account credentials either.

Obviously, this is a thinly veiled scheme to get users to sign up to Flattr. I don't know whether this is a good or bad idea, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

"The idea is to set up a "I'm-ready-to-donate-wall" that only Flattr users are allowed to pass."

Beware that, if I remember correctly, it was not accepted in the Flattr code of conduct. Maybe it has changed lately (I cannot find the reference of this) but check first with some Flattr people if you can legally do that.

Comment: Good point, but https://flattr.com/terms doesn't mention anything to that effect. Still, it's important to check whether this agrees with the spirit of flattr.

Comment: +1. It does have changed recently. Unfortunately Flattr is now happy with any use for Flattr, even paywalls. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9120119/14955 Also note that the winner of this year's Flattr developer contest is a Stackexchange clone that *requires* Flattr membership to do anything, and uses Flattr'ing for votes. http://blog.flattr.net/2012/02/and-the-developer-challenge-winner-is/

Answer (score 1):

You can use "login" to your site with the Flattr OAUTH 2 API.

So what you would do is to connect your site as an third part application to flattr and then let the users authenticate with their Flattr login 
http://developers.flattr.net/v2/#authorization

The first time the users access use your site they have to allow your app access to their Flattr profile.

Moreover, you can authorize a user without gaining access to any non-public features. To get any special access you need to specify the scopes for which you want special access - specify no scopes and the only thing you get to know is that a specific user has a specific account on Flattr.com.

Comment: That certainly works, but it's not quite what I want. After all, it's doing more than I need: it authorizes me to flattr things or to create new things on behalf of the user. Neither do I want to force users to accept my app on their flattr profile.

Comment: You can authorize a user without gaining access to any non-public features. To get any special access you need to specify the scopes for which you want special access - specify no scopes and the only thing you get to know is that a specific user has a specific account on Flattr.com.

Comment: @VoxPelli: Actually, I still can't check whether a user is logged into flattr at any particular point in time, I just obtain the information that he does have an account, right?

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus: That is correct - you can't check whether a user is logged in or not - it's up to the user to tell you that and the API would be the way to ask.

Comment: @VoxPelli: How exactly would I ask him via the API in that case? I can't seem to find anything in the API documentation that allows me to query whether a user is currently logged in when visiting my website.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus: You do what Christopher outlined above - same flow as when you eg. log in to a site with Twitter.