# Using Flattr as Paywall

Tags: payment, flattr

this is a touchy subject with Flattr but I couldn't find a definite answer yet [1]

Is it allowed to use Flattr for a paywall-like flow? My idea is to give users access to a download for a Flattr. They have access to the stream before, so they know what they'll get.

Form the flow i think it would look like this:
User comes to deep link of stream on platform -> clicks connect to flattr -> returns to platform and clicks on [flattr for download] -> thing is flattred in the background and download starts

To finance my platform I'd like users to Flattr my platform in the download flow as well (but give them the opportunity to opt-out).

So, am I allowed to do this? Technically this seems possible with the Flattr API.

[1] https://flattr.com/terms 
[Checking whether a user is logged into Flattr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491121/checking-whether-a-user-is-logged-into-flattr)

Answer (score 1):

Flattr Terms of Use does not prohibit this.

Comment: I believe it is still a touchy subject, though. It seems that (unfortunately?) Flattr will now allow such a thing, but you'd still get a better reception from most users if you found a way to keep payments voluntarily.